# ggplot boxplot: too many outliers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The dataset is available here but I am only using the ones from Year 2010 - 2016 as a subset: https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results/

I am trying to plot the height of different gender with a boxplot and it returns this plot:

[image]
I felt that it is not correct since there are way too many outliers...(mean=175, min=133, max=221).
I was wondering if I need to adjust the Y-axis to include more data points in this boxplot? If so, how can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data = olympics, aes(x = Sex, y = Height) +
 geom_boxplot() +
 labs(title= "Height Distribution of Olympics Athletes by Gender")
```

Also, I was wondering if it is possible to plot such a graph with base R language as well? Thank you!

Comment: The link to the data is not working. Please provide it using e.g. `dput`.

Comment: Hi Kath, thank you for the reminder, I am quite new to Stackoverflow so still trying to figure out how to show an example dataset....but I have just uploaded a new link which will give you the right dataset. Thank you!

Comment: "I felt that it is not correct since there are way too many outliers...(mean=175, min=133, max=221)." Why do you "*feel*" that way? How do the numbers in brackets relate to your "feelings"?

Comment: Just execute `dput(olympics)` in R and paste the output into your question.

Comment: The graph is most likely correct, you just have that many outliers with the ggplots's default for the length of the whiskers enforced. If you want to extend the whiskers beyond an interquartile range of 1.5, you can do so by using `coef` in your call to `boxplot`. An example would be to type `ggplot(data = olympics, aes(x = Sex, y = Height) +
 geom_boxplot(coef = 10) +
 labs(title= "Height Distribution of Olympics Athletes by Gender")`. Note: This will of course only change how your data is displayed

Comment: I would second the points made by @kath and @Roland. It would be much easier if you provided the data using `dput()`. Many users, me included, are not inclined to register for a website and manually download a data set so if you want help, make it a bit easier for us :)

Comment: Hi Tifu, thank you for your answer and tip. I did try dput but since the dataset has 35K objects, the code was long and chaotic, and I couldn't even get running on my computer (I just did dput(olympics), and copy paste the output in R ,is that the right step? It just gave me bunch of errors.). 
I cannot provide just a compressed version of the dataset since my question is about a boxplot visualized based on all the objects, so I thought it would be better to provide the original dataset. Is there a better way to actually display the whole dataset? I will be happy to learn, thank you! :)

Comment: You don't need to give us all of the data, just enough to replicate the issue. Very often you can use the built in data sets in R like `iris`, `mpg`, or `diamonds` to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @VanLindert: No problem. One way to make it manageable is to provide - let's say - only the first 100 rows of your data frame, You can do this by typing `dput(head(olympics, n = 100))`. In case you have lots of columns irrelevant to the question at hand, it might also help to limit the data frame to the `gender` and `height` variables for the question at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow @VanLindert. The best way to get help is to give us code to run that replicates the problem. The `datapasta` and `reprex` packages make this easy to do. https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html

What I suspect is going on is that you are readjusting the y-axis limits and the boxplot keeps changing. When you use `plot + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(130, 225))` or the shorthand `plot + ylim(130, 225)` ggplot filters out values above/below those 130 and 225 and the quartiles are recalculated. If you want to just zoom in on the plot to a specific range, you can use

`plot + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(130, 225))`

Comment: Just be aware that in both of these approaches, your graph no longer reflects the underlying data! You are effectively choosing to show a distribution that - relative to your data - is censored on both edges.

Comment: `coord_cartesian()` will zoom in without removing any underlying data

Comment: Yes, but the graph will be still be biased in the sense that it does not show a number of outliers. It is hard to see a reason in suppressing these data points, especially since in this scenario they are included in calculating the box and whiskers